# Drop down list value not selected because of aync calls for object and options

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, dropdown

I have an angular 4 form for add/update an object written in angular 4.
The form has several dropdown list which options are from API calls.
When updating the object, on ngInit, I get existing object by ID and also get options for drop down list.
But drop down lists not always loads with preselected option.
I know the reason is since all API calls are asynchronous, when object data get fetched earlier than dropdown list options are loaded, the options won't be selected.

What's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: You could wait for both your data and your options before rendering the form for the user to use

Comment: it actually should populate your values to your variable when the data comes through. Any error messages? and please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `forkJoin()` operator, it allows us to take a list of Observables and execute them **in parallel**.  We don't subscribe to each of these Observables individually. Instead, we subscribe to the "container" Observable object created by forkJoin().

See my example:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    const cart = this.stockInventoryService.getCartItems();  // Http request
    const products = this.stockInventoryService.getProducts();  // Http request

    Observable.forkJoin(cart, products)
    .subscribe(([cart, products]: [Stock[], Product[]]) => {
      // ... handle values...
    });
```

Comment: So I guess the idea is each time subscribe event gets called, we will try to set dropdown value?